# How to restore PostgreSQL database backup without psql and pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-restore

I am using postgresql on an embedded device running yocto (customized linux). The package containing postgresql does not provide psql or pg_restore. /usr/bin provides the following tools:

[image]

pg_basebackup indicates that I am able to create backups. But how am I supposed to restore a backup within a terminal? With pg_restore or psql this would not be a problem for me.

**Please note:** I want to use a backup created on my windows/linux computer to create the initial database on the embedded device.

Comment: `psql` and `pg_restore` are **client** side tools. You don't need them on the server to restore a backup. If you can connect from your desktop to the Postgres server running on your device, you can restore the dump from your Windows/Linux computer. `pg_basebackup` is mainly used to bootstrap a second node for replication. There is no equivalent "restore tool for that because it simply creates a copy of the data directory.

Comment: It would be possible to restore a backup via network. However, I want to initialize the embedded system with the first boot providing all necessary files (such as the current database backup). Therefore I need some advice how to restore a backup directly on the server if the backup files are available on the system.

Comment: You can initialize the database over the network, then shutdown Postgres on the device and copy the data directory

Comment: This is no option since I do not want to do this each time manually. I simply want to provide the latest backup files to the server image (currently *.sql) and restore them with the first system boot... It would already be sufficient to run simple *.sql-scripts from the command line, but how can i do that without psql?

Comment: Maybe you can install a "postgres-client" package that includes `psql` from the place where you downloaded the server software?

Comment: After spending much time on solving this problem I simply accepted that I have to restore the database via network after the first boot. It would have been better to configure the database automatically but I can not find an easy approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create backup of the db using command:

```
pg_basebackup -h {host_ip} -D pg_backup  -U {USER}
```

for restoring just change the data folder to pg_backup. Now start the psql server.